# how to mark the needed positions for fitting a Gaussian curve on the plotted data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, lmfit

i'm trying to fit a gaussian lmfit model into my data in a way that the user mark the background points and when he press on a button called "fit" the program fits the curve into the places he marked (similar to the picture i've included [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMfLr.gif)<--here)and print the fitting report 
 and here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel 
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor, Button



x, y = np.loadtxt("fily3.txt", skiprows=1, unpack = True) 



mod2 = GaussianModel()

pars = mod2.guess(y, x=x)  #Estimate initial model parameter values from data
out = mod2.fit(y, pars, x=x) #Fit the model to the data using the supplied Parameters
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

print("Gaussian fit report \n")
print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25))

plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
plt.plot(x, out.best_fit, 'k--', label='best fit')
cursor = Cursor(ax,
            horizOn=True, # Controls the visibility of the horizontal line
            vertOn=True, # Controls the visibility of the vertical line
            color='green',
            linewidth=2.0
            )
def onclick(event):
x1, y1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
print("X-Coordinate :  ",x1," & ", "Y-Coordinate :  ", y1)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.title(" Gaussian model")
plt.xlabel("2-Theta")
plt.ylabel("Intensity")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

`

Comment: Your post doesn't seem to include a concrete question?

Comment: thanks, i fixed it!